# unix map function

Tags: bash, unix, dictionary, sh

I have an array of values `$dates` that I'm transforming:

```
for i in $dates
do
  date -d "1970-01-01 $i sec UTC" '+%a_%D' 
done
```

Is there a way to save the result of this operation so I can pipe it to something else without writing it to a file on disk?

Comment: Are you restricted to bash? If not, I'd recommend doing this in Perl... map comes as part of the package.

Comment: How big is your array?  10s, 100s, 1000s, bigger?  Why can't it be written to disk?  Can you hold the results in another array?  Why not?

Comment: Does your version of `date` support `date -d "@$i" '+%a_%D'`?

Comment: Also, technically `$dates` would be a list rather than an array. Your question is tagged both `[bash]` and `[sh]`. The Bourne shell doesn't support arrays (but Bash does). Are you targeting Bash or is portability a concern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a function:

```
foo () {
        for i in $@
        do
                date -d "1970-01-01 $i sec UTC" '+%a_%D'
        done
}
```

Then you can e.g. send the output to standard error:

```
echo `foo $dates` >&2
```

Comment: What does sending the output to standard error do for you? You could do that without a function: `for ... done >&2`.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: It's not about sending the output to stderr; that was only an example of how to use the function. It's about being able to capture the output without messing around with long expressions like `$(for i in $dates; do date -d "@$i" '+%a_%D'; done)` all the time.

Comment: The surrounding `$(...)` are not necessary.  You can pipe the entire `for` as Dennis has shown.  As in `for ... done | 2nd-command`.

Answer (score 20):

Since you say "transforming" I'm assuming you mean that you want to capture the output of the loop in a variable. You can even replace the contents of your `$dates` variable.

```
dates=$(for i in "$dates"; do date -d "@$i" '+%a_%D'; done)
```

Comment: I was inspired by this and used `bless $(for i in {0..127}; do printf '0x%06x ' $(($i * 0x4000)); done)` to open many files `0x000000, 0x004000, 0x008000, 0x00c000, 0x010000, 0x014000, ...` at once in a logical order.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit vague, but the following may work:

```
for ...
do
 ...
done | ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If using bash, you could use an array:

```
q=0
for i in $dates
do
  DATEARRAY[q]="$(date -d "1970-01-01 $i sec UTC" '+%a_%D')"
  let "q += 1"
done
```

You can then echo / pipe that array to another program. Note that arrays are bash specific, which means this isn't a portable (well, beyond systems that have bash) solution.

Comment: You don't have to escape the quotes inside the `$()`. They are evaluated separately from the ones outside. In fact, in this case it won't work. You can do `array+=(element)` and you don't have to keep track of an index variable.

Comment: Arrays exist in most shells, and they were in csh first, with almost the same syntax (`set DATEARRAY[q]=...`).

Comment: @Dennis - Thanks, I actually added them as an afterthought. @Charles, I don't think they exist in dash, ksh, pdksh or busybox (which is basically dash iirc), hence the warning for portability. Neat to know that they were in csh first, which I don't get to use _nearly_ enough :)

Comment: Busybox has `ash` (Almquist shell) which is a predecessor (?) of `dash` (Debian ash). Neither has arrays. Ksh93 has arrays (I'm not sure about ksh88). The version of `pdksh` (@(#)PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2) I have has arrays. Zsh also has arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it to a FIFO -- a "named pipe" that looks like a file.

Wikipedia has a decent example of its use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe

Comment: Named pipes are really interesting, thanks! I keep getting a deadlock, though. Need to learn more about them.

Answer (score 1):

Edit, didn't see the whole file thing:

```
for i in $dates ; do
    date -d "1970-01-01 $i sec UTC" '+%a_%D'
done |foo
```

Comment: The op specifically mentioned not wanting to write the data to a file.

Comment: Answer 2 with the single I/O redirection should be used rather than the append-per-command in Answer 1.

Comment: @TimPost super late to this reply, but nowhere is there a logical file in this scenario.